# Connecting Ruby rails to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I hope this question is not redundant. I saw a question almost like it but as the problem was a bit different it was no help.

I'm trying to connect my ruby rails Application to my MySQL database when using `sudo rake db:migrate` however (and some other commands) I get the following output

The error says I have a password set but so far as I can tell I do not. I have taken every measure I can think of to ensure that there is none set.

```
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:456:in `real_connect'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:456:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:108:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in `mysql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm still fairly new to this so if there is any pertinent information I have not provided please let me know.

Any help would be vary much appreciated.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: The error says you sent a password to authenticate, not that one is set. This is the dupe of a ton of questions. https://www.google.com/search?q=Mysql%3A%3AError%3A+Access+denied+for+user+%27root%27%40%27localhost%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=Mysql::Error:+Access+denied+for+user+%27root%27%40%27localhost%27+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Is the password getting some from somewhere other than the database.yml file?

Comment: Yeah. Take out the password line of you don't have a password.

Comment: well i got that one fixed. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *(using password: YES)* portion of the error error indicates that you sent a password to authenticate, not that one is set. Remove the `password: whatever` line from your database.yml, if you do not have one set on the database.